# Replacing a relay by a transistor

Tags: power-supply, power, voltage, transistors, capacitor

i'm new in electronic, I made a simple circuit to control a pump it's working, but i'm really not happy of the result.

1. I have to plug 2 power sources because if I have only one for the pump and the board, it fail (I think it's because the pump get too mutch power to start so the sensor dont like it).
2. The circuit is too big (due to the relay size and because of the 1st point).

I think i should use a transistor for replacing the relay ? but i really don't know what kind of transistor I should use...
And may be a capacitor to handle the problem of the pump draining too much power when it start ?
I'm really new and I didn't really understood the usage of capacitors for now ...

[image: Circuit]

This is what my circuit looks like for now, The little thing in the middle with QRD1114 wirten on it it's actually not a "QRD1114", it's a soil moisture sensor like [this one](http://yourduino.com/sunshop2/images/products/large_366_SoilMoisture1-450.jpg), it's just here to illustrate.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 2):

First - don't power a pump from USB unless it will consume less than 200mA. Keep that in mind for future applications/projects. DC motors will draw very large start-up currents, and this can blow your USB hubs or their fuses, and other nasty things. Of course, a 1.5A USB phone charger plugged into the wall would be fine for most things! Always be careful about your choice of power inputs, often noobies will forget or downplay the importance of checking that all of their rated inputs/output power requirements in the project are going to work.

According to a dodgy datasheet for that product I just found, it can pull up to 360mA at 7.2V, so make sure it's not running off a computer USB port.

Because the load is only 360mA though, you can get away with a nice and small MOSFET as a switch instead of a relay. Because the pump is just a DC motor, you can switch it with a low-side N-channel MOSFET configuration.

Here is an example circuit for you:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLE5Sl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The way this works is the USB 5V+ goes into the pump pin, and the pump's other pin goes to the MOSFET's Drain pin. The MOSFET's Source pin goes to GROUND.

Make sure to tie the two difference supply's GROUND pins together.

The SIGNAL input to the MOSFET's Gate pin comes from your Arduino. When the SIGNAL goes high, the MOSFET will turn on, and act like the relay did. When the SIGNAL goes low, it will turn off the MOSFET. The pull down resistor R2 is there to ensure it actually turns off, and will also prevent a noisy start-up condition triggering the pump.

The resistor R1 is optional, but good practice.

You should also probably have a Schottky diode from the -ve Pin of the pump to the +ve Pin of the pump in the way I've drawn it, as an inductive voltage spike clamp for when the pump turns off.

I suggest you DO indeed put a 1000mF or more capacitor (go for a 16V or 35V rated one just for the funz. If you do a 6.3V one, it may pop if you don't put the over voltage clamp on it as I mentioned).

This capacitor will assist with the start-up surge currents which can cause brown-outs and other issues as you have encountered.

You may want to properly filter/protect the sensor too, by putting a 0.1uF (100nF) capacitor on the power supply leads for it.

Comment: Thanks ! I will try this ! I mentioned usb power because it's the easiest (and cheapest) way to get 5v, but I use wall adapters, the system have to work 24/7 even when my computer is off :)

Comment: I have a wide choice of transistor and capacitor at home, but in terms of mostfet 
I got only one at the moment, it's a "SFC  2812EC  7808" i have no idea what it means, can i use it ? and for the capacitor, I have to put it between the usb+ and the +ve pin of the motor?

Comment: no idea what that is either @Touk,  are you sure that's even a MOSFET? How do you know it is?

Comment: Hmmm, no i's not a mosfet... i will have to go in paris to buy one...i keep you updated.

Comment: You have to protect the MOSFET against voltage spikes (inductive load) with a schottky diode. Otherwise, your MOSFET will be burnt within a couple of cycles.
You should draw it in the circuit, it is very important.

Comment: @GleisonStorto yes, in my answer is this: "You should also probably have a Schottky diode from the -ve Pin of the pump to the +ve Pin of the pump in the way I've drawn it, as an inductive voltage spike clamp for when the pump turns off."  I will add it now, because you have requested it.